# Where are the Stack Exchange servers located?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, server, hosting

Where are the Stack Exchange servers located? And who is the hosting provider for  Stack Exchange?

Answer (score 1):

Based on traceroute and [our community blog](http://blog.serverfault.com/2010/10/29/1432571770/), Stack Exchange servers are located in New York City in USA in Stack Exchange Data Center, but two database server are located in Oregon.

```
traceroute to stackexchange.com (198.252.206.16), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  192.168.0.1 (192.168.0.1)  2.391 ms  3.030 ms  3.449 ms
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
 4  poz-bg2.neo.tpnet.pl (83.1.4.48)  31.344 ms  41.221 ms  42.024 ms
 5  poz-r3.tpnet.pl (80.50.156.225)  61.958 ms  65.688 ms  66.756 ms
 6  poz-r2.tpnet.pl (194.204.175.206)  66.692 ms  26.451 ms  36.711 ms
 7  hbg-b1-link.telia.net (213.248.103.61)  48.539 ms  56.909 ms  58.151 ms
 8  hbg-bb2-link.telia.net (213.155.135.84)  58.592 ms  41.965 ms  55.375 ms
 9  ldn-bb2-link.telia.net (80.91.247.213)  80.567 ms ldn-bb2-link.telia.net (213.155.132.249)  57.895 ms  70.920 ms
10  nyk-bb2-link.telia.net (213.248.65.94)  124.116 ms nyk-bb2-link.telia.net (213.155.135.71)  128.861 ms nyk-bb2-link.telia.net (80.91.248.254)  124.576 ms
11  nyk-b6-link.telia.net (213.155.133.13)  139.194 ms  139.441 ms  139.618 ms
12  internap-ic-150761-nyk-b5.c.telia.net (213.248.81.150)  126.056 ms  137.521 ms  124.250 ms
13  border1.po2-20g-bbnet2.nym008.pnap.net (216.52.95.65)  134.481 ms  127.553 ms  126.647 ms
14  stackexchange-1.border1.nym008.pnap.net (74.201.252.22)  135.698 ms  123.859 ms  138.983 ms
15  stackoverflow.com (198.252.206.16)  140.112 ms  137.584 ms  125.088 ms
```